# Freezes during OS boot

Tags: freeze, hardware-failure, machine-check-exception

Yesterday I had freezes while loading OS.

Windows would BSOD with "MACHINE_CHECK_EXCEPTION".
Linux would freeze or give me this: [image: http://i.imgur.com/Mrym1D2.jpg]

```
$ mcelog -ascii
Hardware event. This is not a software error.
CPU 0 BANK 3 
MISC fffff802bd0fa9d7 ADDR fffff802bd0fa9d7 
TIME 1475007075 Tue Sep 27 22:11:15 2016
MCG status:
MCi status:
Uncorrected error
Error enabled
MCi_MISC register valid
MCi_ADDR register valid
Processor context corrupt
MCA: Internal Timer error
STATUS be00000000800400 MCGSTATUS 0
CPUID Vendor Intel Family 6 Model 94
SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 74
```

Same issue with no Graphics card.

Disassembled and reassembled everything, rotated CPU by 720 degrees, nothing changed.

Reset CMOS, flashed new BIOS, nothing changed.

Run memcheck, it passes in safe mode (single core), freezes in multi core, but apparently it's common (screen of freeze, fails consistently in this very place). [image: http://i.imgur.com/fmjfrrO.jpg]

Hardware:

- i5 6600k
- Z170-Gaming K3
- 8GB single DIMM DDR4 (I believe its this: BLT8G4D30AETA)

Works since today (After 6 hours of downtime I managed to run this at 01:05 with seemingly no changes to anything), but I want to find faulty piece.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the bios to default?

Comment: Reset CMOS, flashed new BIOS.

Comment: Well according to the error there is an RAM error in bank 4 I assume its dim 4, but I am not sure. But it could also be an driver issue aswell. I suggest removing memory 1 by 1 and see which one does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the problem is now fixed?

If so, there could be different reasons why this happened, but I suspect it is (was?) a timing issue related to your memory.  I would look at Gigabyte's website for the "Memory Support List" (aka Qualified Vendors List) for your motherboard, which lists known-good memory chips:

[Memory support list for Z170-Gaming K3](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5720#memory%20support%20list)

I looked but didn't find the string "8G4D3" there, so I suspect your memory module isn't listed.  If I was working Gigabyte's tech support that's the first place I'd blame :)

Why would the system now be working?  When you reset CMOS or reflashed the BIOS your probably reset some memory-related timing settings that either fixed the problem or temporarily made it go away.  If you were doing any kind of overclocking and/or if your memory module was borderline (unsupported by mobo, bad batch, bad temps that day, etc.),  random/intermittent issues are not at all uncommon.

To save yourself the headache, I would start with a supported memory chip.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you perform the steps below and check if it resolves your issue:

1. On the Lock Screen press on Shift Key + power icon located on the right bottom corner of the screen.
2. Press on " Restart Anyway" this will take you to the Recovery Environment.
3. Click on "Troubleshoot" and the "Advanced Option" and the "Startup  Repair."

Comment: 1. My Windows wouldn't boot that far.
2. Not sure how that would help (it seems pretty obvious even, to my eyes that its hardware problem), can you elaborate?